# How do I find the top 100 names from the two files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is what I have now

```
def BabyNames():
RFile = open("boys.dat.txt","r")
OFile = open("girls.dat.txt","r")

babyNameLst = []
result=[]



for line in RFile:
    line = line.strip()
    name,count= line.split(",")
    name= name.strip()
    New = (count,name)
    babyNameLst.append(New)
for line in OFile:
    line= line.strip()
    name,count = line.split(",")
    name=name.strip()
    New = (count,name)
    babyNameLst.append(New)

sorted_Nums = sorted(babyNameLst, reverse= True)

print(sorted_Nums[:100])
```

Example **boys.dat.txt**:

```
Jacob  ,204760
Michael ,187948
Joshua ,173395
Matthew ,168437
Andrew ,151667
Christopher ,148897
Daniel ,145989
Joseph ,144904
Ethan ,140215
Nicholas ,139296
William ,138425
Anthony ,136813
David ,129579
Ryan ,129284
Tyler ,126685
```

Example **girls.dat.txt**:

```
Emily  ,170901
Madison ,142410
Emma ,125605
Hannah ,124651
Abigail ,105519
Olivia ,104454
Ashley ,103995
Samantha ,101188
Alexis ,100782
Sarah ,96907
Elizabeth ,96682
Isabella ,88941
Alyssa ,85267
Grace ,83188
Lauren ,77841
Taylor ,76907
Jessica ,76093
Brianna ,74945
Kayla ,73756
```

These are the names and the count of how many times used. I need to find out the top 100 of these boy and girl names using the counts. How would I do that? The counts tell me the number of times the name is chosen, need to largest top 100 count of the names.

**It would go in the order :**
204740 Jacob
187948 Michael
173395 Joshua
170901 Emily
168437 Andrew
etc...

Comment: You seem to be using a non standard csv file. Is the file just 1 line? Please post a link or show us an example of the original file.

Comment: There is two files the examples of the files are below, the boys.dat.txt file is shown, also the girls.dat.txt file below my code.

Comment: One match per line or everything  in one line? this isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your sorted to

```
sorted(babyNameLst, key=lambda tup: int(tup[0]), reverse=True)
```

Also a little note: according to PEP 8 for variable names underscore should be used only: baby_name_list. Camlecase is allowed for Classes

Comment: its sorting by names now, it sorting if name begins with a it will put it first I need it in order by largest number

Comment: In that case just change tup[1] to be tup[0] in my above solution and it will work.

Comment: This is the index of value in your tuple. 0 for count and 1 for name.

Comment: [('10016', 'Troy'), ('1002', 'Tatianna'), ('1004', 'Silvia'), ('10051', 'Gerardo'), ('10069', 'Skyler'), ('10069', 'Oliver'), ('10069', 'Lizbeth')  it gives me this result which I am not looking for, the result I am looking for  is 204740 Jacob 187948 Michael 173395 Joshua 170901 Emily 168437 Andrew

Comment: It sorted in ascending order by default, just add reverse=True as you did before. And as far as your count is string it should be converted to int as well. See my edited answer.

Comment: That is where I messed it not converting my string count into int. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
boys = pd.read_csv("boys.txt", names=['names','births'])
print(boys)
```

---

```
          Jacob   204760
0       Michael   187948
1        Joshua   173395
2       Matthew   168437
3        Andrew   151667
4   Christopher   148897
5        Daniel   145989
6        Joseph   144904
7         Ethan   140215
8      Nicholas   139296
9       William   138425
10      Anthony   136813
11        David   129579
12         Ryan   129284
13        Tyler   126685
```

---

If you need to print the top 5, you can use:

```
print(boys.head(5))
```

---

```
      names  births
0    Jacob   204760
1  Michael   187948
2   Joshua   173395
3  Matthew   168437
4   Andrew   151667
```

---

> I need both boys and girls together in one list

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) both dataframes, i.e.:

```
b = pd.read_csv("boys.txt", names=['names','births'])
g = pd.read_csv("girls.txt", names=['names','births'])
x = pd.concat([b, g]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(x)
```

---

```
           names  births
0         Jacob   204760
1       Michael   187948
2        Joshua   173395
3       Matthew   168437
4        Andrew   151667
5   Christopher   148897
6        Daniel   145989
7        Joseph   144904
8         Ethan   140215
9      Nicholas   139296
10      William   138425
11      Anthony   136813
12        David   129579
13         Ryan   129284
14        Tyler   126685
15       Emily    170901
...
```

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the girls' list and the boys' list are sorted separately( As with what I can see)

So what you need is to get the sorted array from both lists.

What you are looking for is quite similar to the merging algorithm in merge sort.

---

---

Assume, that both arrays are sorted in ascending order and we want resulting array to maintain the same order. Algorithm to merge two arrays A[0..m-1] and B[0..n-1] into an array C[0..m+n-1] is as following:

1. Introduce read-indices i, j to traverse arrays A and B, accordingly.
   Introduce write-index k to store position of the first free cell in
   the resulting array. By default i = j = k = 0.
2. At each step: if both
   indices are in range (i < m and j < n), choose minimum of (A[i],
   B[j]) and write it to C[k]. Otherwise go to step 4.
3. Increase k and index of the array, algorithm located minimal value at, by one.
   Repeat step 2.
4. Copy the rest values from the array, which index is
   still in range, to the resulting array.

---

```
algorithm merge(A, B) is
inputs A, B : list
returns list

C := new empty list
while A is not empty and B is not empty do
    if head(A) ≤ head(B) then
        append head(A) to C
        drop the head of A
    else
        append head(B) to C
        drop the head of B

// By now, either A or B is empty. It remains to empty the other input list.
while A is not empty do
    append head(A) to C
    drop the head of A
while B is not empty do
    append head(B) to C
    drop the head of B

return C
```

This is the pseudo code of the merging algorithm. Hope it makes sense. Cheers !!!